# Drop down view in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsview, nswindow

I'm looking to create a 'drop down' view that falls in front of the main window. An example of this would be the window that drops down when you click 'Advanced' in System Preferences->Networking.

If someone could point me in the right direction documentation-wise that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's called a [sheet](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000002-BABFIBIA).  Here's a [quick introduction](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000014.php) and the Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000002-BABFIBIA).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /articles/000014.php was not found on this server.